# Coerce the HttpResponse into an item of the specified type, complete with custom methods

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I have a class which represents the structure of the data coming back from an API.  I have added a couple of convenience methods, which apply logic to those fields to return a calculated value.

When I use HttpClient to request the data, then try to interact with those convenience methods, it doesn't work.  I get an error:

```
TypeError: item.<method> is not a function. (In 'item.<method>()', 'item.<method>' is undefined)
```

It's as if the object is not instantiated as an instance of class Item, it is just verified that you never use it as anything but an Item.  So, all the functions defined in the class definition are not attached to the object.

Is there a way to not just type-check, but coerce the JSON into being an actual object of type Item?

I suppose I could add a constructor that takes the generic object and copies all the fields into the new object's fields.  But that not only seems highly inefficient, but reeks of code smell.

Is there a clean way to get the object returned from HttpClient/HttpResponse to include those convenience functions?

I tried using `Object.assign()` as @DeborahK suggested:

```
return this.http.get<Item[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/view/projects`, this.options)
  .map( (response: HttpResponse<Item[]>) => {
    var result = Object.assign(new Array<Item>(),response.body);
    console.log( result );
    return result;
  });
```

What gets written to the console is an array, it contains all the data, but none of the elements are Items.  Probably because I'm not creating an array of items, I'm creating an array that is supposed to contain items.

So I modified it like so:

```
return this.http.get<Item[]>(`${this.apiUrl}/view/projects`, this.options)
  .map( (response: HttpResponse<Item[]>) => {
    var result = response.body.map( (item:Item) => 
      Object.assign(new Item(),item) );
    console.log( result );
    return result;
  });
```

And that creates an array of Items.  Yay!  Problem solved!  Thank you @DeborahK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HttpClient provides the data in the layout that matches the provided class or interface, but as you've seen, it does not actually create an instance of the class itself.

In your .subscribe, you can do something like this:

```
Object.assign(new Item(), data);
```

Where `Item` is the name of your class and `data` is the data coming back from the http request.

This creates a new instance of your class and assigns the returned data to that instance.

If you want to provide a bit more code I could provide a more specific example.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't seem to have worked.  In order to add clarity, I'll update the question with the code that I tried.